# Object required error while declaring custom sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have the below code to move data. This works fine when the default sheet names are used. However when I use a different name for the sheets (instead of sheet1, sheet2) I get "Object required" error.

Here "Latency" is sheet1 and "TP" is sheet2.

Can someone guide me on how to fix it?

```
Sub sbMoveData()
    Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    'Find last roe in Sheet1
    lRow = Latency.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To lRow
    If UCase(Latency.Range("E" & i)) = "COMPATIBLE" And UCase(Latency.Range("O" & i)) = "Pass" Then
    Sheets("Latency").Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TP").Range("A" & j)
    j = j + 1
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *Latency* is clearly a worksheet, but has not been **Dimmed** or **Set** in the scope of this sub.

Comment: I'll try to say what @Gary's Student wrote above, where in this `Sub` do you have `Dim Latency As Worksheet` , and later `Set Latency = Worksheets("Yoursheetname")` ? While later you are using it correctly with `Sheets("Latency")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did it right at the line

```
Worksheets("Latency").Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TP").Range("A" & j)
```

but before, you used `Latency` as if it was an object, while it is just a name. To obtain a sheet object by its name, always use `sheets("name")`, or `Worksheets("name")`

```
Sub sbMoveData()
    Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    'Find last roe in Sheet1
    With Worksheets("Latency")
        lRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        j = 1
        For i = 1 To lRow
            If UCase(.Range("E" & i)) = "COMPATIBLE" And UCase(.Range("O" & i)) = "Pass" Then
                .Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TP").Range("A" & j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and there was no error while running it. But there was no result also..the code didnt work

Comment: @walterwhile Then there is another mistake, probably in the worksheet's data... maybe there is no match. step into the code and see if you find any matches. FWIW, the problem of this question is solved.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `Sheet1.Range`, you're referencing a global-scope `Worksheet` object that VBA automatically declares for you. That "free" object points to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` by default, and using it instead of fetching the exact same object reference from the `Worksheets` collection is a very good idea.

Now, if you labelled that `Sheet1` worksheet "Latency", you've set its `Name`, but not its `CodeName` - and it's the `CodeName` that VBA uses to create the global identifier you can use in code. You can change that in the *Properties* toolwindow (F4):

[image: Properties]

Notice the `(Name)` (first) property still says "Sheet1"? Change that to `Latency` and now this code becomes valid:

```
lRow = Latency.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

[image: Properties]

Now, once you start using the `Latency` global identifier, *use it everywhere* - don't go and start fetching the exact same worksheet reference off the `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` or `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` collections!

Instead of this:

```
Sheets("Latency").Range("M" & i).Copy
```

You do that:

```
Latency.Range("M" & i).Copy
```

Do the same for the other sheet, too. Note that the `Sheets` collection can contain charts, not just worksheets - when you *do* fetch a worksheet object reference from a collection (say, from a worksheet you've created at runtime), you should use the `Worksheets` collection to do so.

You should also look into properly [indenting](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) (disclaimer: this link points to my pet project's website) your code, too.

Comment: FWIW I'd go with `LatencySheet` and `TpSheet` instead of `Latency` and `TP`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
If UCase(Latency.Range("E" & i)) = "COMPATIBLE" And UCase(Latency.Range("O" & i)) = "Pass" Then
Worksheets("Latency").Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TP").Range("A" & j)
j = j + 1
End If
```

Comment: Same error..point out to `lRow = Latency.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row`

Comment: maybe you just change the sheet display name and not the actual sheet name so try replacing latency.range() to Worksheets("Latency").range()